# Timeout a sql execution C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

At what point does the application actually execute the query? Is it 
Is it at connection open adapter.fill?

```
     if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == false)
        {

        try
        {

            superset = new DataSet();


            string[] lines = BranchTBox.Lines;

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {

                if (lines[i].Length == 3)
                {

                    if (qachk.Checked == false)
                    {
                        connectionString = "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}; Database=" + lines[i] + "; Hostname=" + lines[i] + "." + lines[i] + ".xx; Port = xx; Protocol = xx; Uid=xx; Pwd= xx;";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (Control child in panel4.Controls)
                        {
                            if ((child as RadioButton).Checked)
                            {
                                qaserver = child.Text;
                            }
                        }

                        connectionString = "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}; Database=" + lines[i] + "; Hostname=" + qaserver + ".xx; Port = xx; Protocol = xx; Uid=xx; Pwd= xx;";

                    }





                    connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

                    adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(masterquery, connection);


                    connection.Open();
                      if ((backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == false) && (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open))
                      {
                          if (superset != null)
                          {


                              adapter.Fill(superset);
                              superset.Merge(superset);
                              connection.Close();
                          }

                      }






                    //progressBar1.Value = 0;

                }

               if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == false)
                      {
                          if (superset != null)
                          {

                              dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)(() => dataGridView1.DataSource = superset));
                              dataGridView1.Invoke((Action)(() => dataGridView1.DataSource = superset.Tables[0]));


                              timer1.Stop();
                              progressBar1.Invoke((Action)(() => progressBar1.Value = 0));
                              tabControl1.Invoke((Action)(() => tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3));
                          }
               }



                      //  progressBar1.Invoke((Action)(() => progressBar1.Value = 0));






            }




        }
```

I'm trying to only run a query for 30 seconds the have it timeout. I tried adding the connection timeout to the connection string but that didn't work. Any other suggestions? Can I try a try catch clause?

Comment: Connection timeout is not the same as command timeout, which is usually expressed as a property of a SqlCommand object (adapter.SelectCommand?) If you post more code, we can help identify.

Comment: I'm using the IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER does that make a difference?

Comment: What do you mean "have it time out but not stop it"? That doesn't make sense to me. And yes, the Fill method is what actually executes the command in this case.

Comment: @Sewder - only that you would be using OdbcCommand or OleDbCommand or something other than SqlCommand. It still has the same property, and the driver should honor the value provided.

Comment: @mason so it's looping through multiple databases so I just wanted it to close out the connection and then loop to the next database connection, I just need to figure out how to cancel the command now.

Comment: @StingyJack Hmm I don't have many optiosn for OdbcDataAdapter, the options only show .equals or referenceequals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mason points out, the Fill method is what executes the command.

Your data adapter would need this extra statement in the middle to increase the timeout.

```
adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(masterquery, connection);
adapter.SelectCommand.Timeout = 60;
connection.Open();
```

more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, there is no way to use a timeout and allow the query to continue.

Comment: Thahks! Is there a catch I can do, once it times out? Like show a message box if it does go over 60 seconds?

Comment: You can wrap in a try catch, sure. Just catch the correct exception type.

Answer (score 0):

The query is executed on `adapter.Fill()`. To change the command timeout set the `masterquery.CommandTimeout` to a value (in seconds) or 0 for no timeout